# inserting an additional notes between two words and above the sentence

Tags: macros

Please suppose there is enough space between lines of a paragraph in a text. I wish to insert an additional note between two words of a certain sentence and above that (between two lines of the paragraph) as below example. However we have to insert a symbol same as `\lor` between two mentioned words:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with Ti*K*z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\tikzset{%
every picture/.style ={remember picture}}
\tikzset{%
na/.style = {inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}}%
\newcommand{\upset}[2]{\tikz\node[na](word){#1};%
\tikz[overlay]\node at ([yshift=3mm,xshift=0.6mm]word.0){$\overset{\text{#2.}}{\lor}$};%
}

\begin{document}

This is a \upset{sentence}{It is above typed sentence} just for example. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice.  However, there is extra space after the insert.  This may be caused by "unprotected" line endings in the tikz code.  Try ending each line with a `%` to get rid of them.  (This is a guess.  I don't have a tex system available to test.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, Thank you for your hint. I tried to do what you said.